# bootable USB with UPDATABLE Changes 2

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, usb, live-usb

I have created an USB disk as explained [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/), but changes to a vi cretaed file named "h" were not saved to next boot. WHY?

Comment: A Pendrive made using Rufus is easy to make persistent: https://askubuntu.com/questions/291696/how-to-make-an-already-live-ubuntu-pen-drive-a-persistent-one/1118414#1118414

Answer (score 1):

### Changing Live Pendrive to Persistent Pendrive

That works with both BIOS and UEFI

Many people prefer a Persistent pendrive that will save changes.

- Create a Live pendrive using Rufus or similar.
- Boot the pendrive **toram** to make the drive editable, (press <kbd>Shift</kbd> when booting, press <kbd>Esc</kbd> from language, press <kbd>F6</kbd>, press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, type {space}toram after "quiet splash ---", and press Enter.
- Create a casper-rw file:

  ```
  sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=casper-rw bs=1M count=512
  sudo mkfs.ext3 -L casper-rw -F casper-rw
  ```

  (where count=512 is persistence size, with max 4GB).
- Move the new casper-rw file from home to the root of the Live Pendrive.
- Edit ***/isolinux/txt.cfg***, (for BIOS boot persistence) and ***/boot/grub/grub.cfg***, (for UEFI boot persistence), add a space and the word "persistent" after "quiet splash ---".
- Shut down and reboot the persistent drive.